# Select right percentile from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select right value from joined table based on the value in more than one column.
I started sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f92daa/2
Main table:

```
id  val
1   1
2   4
3   67
4   78
5   22
```

Joined table:

```
obs_id  perc1   perc2   perc3   perc4   perc5   perc6   perc7   perc8   perc9   perc10
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
3   10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
4   10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
5   10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Expected result should be:

```
id  val perc
1   1   1
2   4   4
3   67  70
4   78  80
5   22  30
```

perc - should be number from perc table (joined by ids) not greater than highest possible value form columns perc1-10

Table perc stores percentiles of observations. The goal is to find which interval hit the value from main table and take the upper band.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to do this. This assumes perc1 < perc2 < perc3 < perc4 < ... and so on.

```
SELECT obs.id, obs.val, 
case when val <= perc1 then perc1 
     when val <= perc2 then perc2 
     when val <= perc3 then perc3
     when val <= perc4 then perc4 
     when val <= perc5 then perc5 
     when val <= perc6 then perc6 
     when val <= perc7 then perc7 
     when val <= perc8 then perc8 
     when val <= perc9 then perc9
     when val <= perc10 then perc10 
     end
perc
FROM obs
INNER JOIN perc
ON obs.id = perc.obs_id
```

[**`SQL Fiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f92daa/11)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `perc` table will have always the values in **ascending** order `then`

```
select 
a.id, a.val,

case
when b.perc1 >= a.val then b.perc1
when b.perc2 >= a.val then b.perc2
when b.perc3 >= a.val then b.perc3
when b.perc4 >= a.val then b.perc4
when b.perc5 >= a.val then b.perc5
when b.perc6 >= a.val then b.perc6
when b.perc7 >= a.val then b.perc7
when b.perc8 >= a.val then b.perc8
when b.perc9 >= a.val then b.perc9
when b.perc10 >= a.val then b.perc10
end as perc

from idval a , perc b
where a.id = b.obs_id
```